# Let me assume that the function $f(x,y,z,w)$ is continuous. Is the $\max_{w} f(x,y,z,w)$ continuous?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity, maxima-minima

Let me assume that the function $f(x,y,z,w)$ is continuous. Is the $\max_{w} f(x,y,z,w)$ continuous?

Since $f(x,y,z,w)$ is continuous, it is seperately continuous for each $x,y,z,$ and $w$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. This is a nice question.

The answer depends on the domain of the function $f$. If this is not restricted, the answer is **No**. For example, consider
$$f(x,w) = f_0(x \cdot w)$$ for $w \ge 0, \, x \in \mathbb{R}$ where 
$$
f_0(x) = \begin{cases} -1 \; (x < -1) \\
x \; (-1 \le x \le 1) \\  1 \; (x > 1) 
\end{cases}
$$

Then $\max_w f(x,w) = 1$ if $x > 0$ and $\max_w f(x,w) =0$ if $x \le 0$. This is not continuous.

**Edited**

At the very least, the $x$ - sections of the domain of $f$ should be compact sets. As shown in other posts and comments, this is however not sufficient.

Comment: Restricting to, say $0\le w\le 2$ (and also $x$ in an appropriate interval), we can get the same counterexample on a compact domain, can't we?

Comment: @Berci I think, for very small $x$, argmax$f(x,w)$ is $\infty$.

Comment: @Hans Engler  Can I get the proof for a compact set case?

Comment: While a compact domain rules out this style of counterexample, there are other things that can go wrong. See my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3155117/continuity-proof-for-compact-domain) for an example.

Comment: Thank you, I have edited my post.