# Continuity proof "If $f(x,y,z,w)$ is continuous and domains of $x,y,z,w$ are all convex set, then $\max_{w} f(x,y,z,w)$ is continuous."

Tags: continuity, convex-analysis, maxima-minima

There is the answer about the continuity.

[Continuity proof for compact domain](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3155117/continuity-proof-for-compact-domain)

I want to know how to prove that
"If $f(x,y,z,w)$ is continuous and domains of $x,y,z,w$ are all convex set, then $\max_{w} f(x,y,z,w)$ is continuous."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, what jmerry conjectured regarding convexity was wrong.

Even if there is a convex compact domain, then $\max_w f(x,y,z,w)$ does not need to be continuous.

For our counterexample, wlog we omit the $z$ variable.

Consider the set
$$
C=\{(x,y,w)\in\mathbb R^3 | 0 \leq w \leq 1, (x-w)^2+y^2\leq w^2 \}.
$$
Then it can be shown that this set is convex and compact.
We define the function
$f(x,y,w):=-w$.

Then, for $x,y$ such that $(x-1)^2+y^2=1$ but $x\neq0$ we have
$$
g(x,y):=\max_w f(x,y,w)=f(x,y,1)=-1.
$$
For $x=y=0$ instead we have
$$
g(0,0):=\max_w f(x,y,w)=f(0,0,0)=0.
$$
Since there is a sequence $(x_n,y_n)$ such that $(x_n-1)^2+(y_n-1)^2=1$ and $x_n\neq0$
and $(x_n,y_n)\to(0,0)$, this shows that $g$ is not continuous.

Comment: $(0,0,1)$ is in your slanted cone $C$. That's not a counterexample; $g$ just comes out to be identically $-1$ on the domain $(x-1)^2+y^2\le 1$.

Comment: @jmerry thank you for pointing out my mistake. Now I exchanged $\min$ with $\max$ as in the original question. Now $f(0,0,0)$ has a larger value than $f(0,0,1)$ and thus $g(0,0)=0\neq -1$. This should fix my counterexample

Comment: OK, now it's there. A full formula: $g(x,y)=-(x^2+y^2)/2x$ for $x>0$, $g(0,0)=0$.